# VB.NET - Chart cannot plot anything less than 1, ex: 0, -1, -2

Tags: vb.net, charts

My chart just will crash(exit Try) when plotting anything less than 1. Does anyone know why? With positive numbers it plots great! I am feeding it Double values and the X and Y datatype is set to Auto in properties.

If the values are positve it is fine:

Dim dataStr As String = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,*"

```
Dim dataStr As String = "-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10,*"
            Try
                Chart1.Series(0).Points.Clear()
                dataStr = dataStr.Replace(",*", "") ' Remove last comma and *
                Dim myArray = Array.ConvertAll(dataStr.Split(","c), AddressOf Convert.ToDouble)
                For Each point As Integer In myArray
                    Chart1.Series(0).Points.Add(myArray(point - 1))
                Next
            Catch
            End Try
```

Comment: The Try..Catch..End Try is hiding the problem from you. Comment them out to see the error message which will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Your point variable is not a looping index, so it doesn't "point" to the correct index in the myArray array.  Never use an empty try-catch.

Comment: Thank you both, your comments are well received and applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: To avoid exception when using a different dataStr value (as per LarsTech comment) you can use For loop instead as follows:

```
    Dim dataStr As String = "-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-20,*"
    Try
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.Clear()
        dataStr = dataStr.Replace(",*", "") ' Remove last comma and *

        Dim myArray = Array.ConvertAll(dataStr.Split(","c), AddressOf Convert.ToDouble)
        Dim max As Integer = myArray.Length
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To max - 1
            Chart1.Series(0).Points.Add(myArray(i))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Ok this did it. I appreciate your time and thank you for your clear solution.

Comment: FYI: MsgBox(ex.Message) didn't work. I had to use MsgBox("Error: " & Err.Description).

The ex caused an run error.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are indexing a negative value. You can use the absolute value of point variable, as shown below.

```
    Dim dataStr As String = "-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10,*"

    Try
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.Clear()
        dataStr = dataStr.Replace(",*", "") ' Remove last comma and *
        Dim myArray = Array.ConvertAll(dataStr.Split(","c), AddressOf Convert.ToDouble)
        For Each point As Integer In myArray
           Chart1.Series(0).Points.Add(myArray(Math.Abs(point) - 1))
        Next
    Catch ex as exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Try `Dim dataStr As String = "-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-20,*"`

Comment: Can I ask why -20 would make a difference? The string contains the data to be plotted, so why would it matter what negative values are in the string? In my case 0 failed, and any number less than that as well failed.

Comment: FYI: I tried -20 and it was fine with the green check solution. Then I tried more nasty data and it worked well too. Ex "0,0,0.01,-20,-1.09,1,2,32,-8,9,*"

Comment: In my first answer I modified slightly your code and as a result it works only for an arithmetic sequence that is reduced by 1 as it is the dataStr of your code. In case when dataStr is not linear (like LarsTech gave as example) it does not work because in the code we reduce the value by one: Chart1.Series(0).Points.Add(myArray(Math.Abs(point) - 1))

So in my second answer I changed the code to a For loop using Chart1.Series(0).Points.Add(myArray(i)) instead. 
This works with any sequence. By the way value -20 is not needed in order to work.